# Why is StreetView JS API not correctly mirroring StreetView Static API?

Tags: javascript, google-maps-api-3, google-maps-static-api, google-street-view

I am trying to use the JS StreetView API to let the user select a view they wish to use for a static StreetView image. I've built a basic test as located on my [sandbox](http://sandbox.drewsonne.com/maps.html) instance (and below for future posterity).

When the page first loads, the StreetView view-port loads, and the static image reflecting that view-port loads correctly. If I pan around without my from my position, the static image updates correctly.

I'm using calls made on `pov_changed`, `position_changed`, and `visible_changed` events to invoke the updating of the static image. I put a half a second delay between the firing of these events to not invoke quota errors.

**My problem is this:**
If I use any of the 'clickToGo' actions to change my location, the location (latitude/longitude) shown in my static StreetView does not correctly reflect the JS StreetView view-port. From what i can see, the pov (fov/zoom, heading, pitch) are all correct, but my location is not.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="http://maps.google.com/maps/api/js?sensor=false"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript">

          function initialize() {
            var panorama = new google.maps.StreetViewPanorama(document.getElementById("pano"), {
              position: new google.maps.LatLng(42.345573,-71.098326),
              pov: {
                heading: 34,
                pitch: 10,
                zoom: 1
              }
            });

            /**
             * Build static URL from streetview JS instance settings
             */
            function getStaticUrl(secure) {
                secure = (secure) ? 's' : '';
                var latlng = panorama.getPosition();
                var pov = panorama.getPov();
                var url = "http" + secure + "://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/streetview?size=500x400&location=" + encodeURIComponent(latlng.lat() + ", " + latlng.lng()) + "&fov=" + (180 / Math.pow(2, pov.zoom)) + "&heading=" + encodeURI(pov.heading) + "&pitch=" + encodeURI(pov.pitch) + "&sensor=false";
                console.log("lat: " + latlng.lat() + "     " + "lng: " + latlng.lng());
                console.log("img src: " + url);
                return url;
            }

            /**
             * To stop overusing quota errors with the static streetview API, wait half a second after streetview has stopped moving to
             * update image preview.
             */
            var _updateStreetViewWait = 0;
            var _handleStreetViewPovChange = function() {
                clearTimeout(_updateStreetViewWait);
                _updateStreetViewWait = setTimeout(function() {
                    var linkUrl = getStaticUrl();
                    $('#link').html("<a target='_blank' href='" + linkUrl + "'><img src='" + linkUrl + "'/></a>");
                }, 500);
            };
            google.maps.event.addListener(panorama, 'pov_changed', _handleStreetViewPovChange);
            google.maps.event.addListener(panorama, 'position_changed', _handleStreetViewPovChange);
            google.maps.event.addListener(panorama, 'visible_changed', _handleStreetViewPovChange);
          }
        </script>
    </head>
    <body onload="initialize()">
      <div id="pano" style="width: 500px; height: 400px"></div>
      <div id="link" style="width:100%; height: 2%"></div>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: In the interest of getting my problem fixed, can the person who marked the question to be closed as 'not constructive' tell me how I can rephrase my problem as an appropriate question?

Comment: The two different APIs use different projection systems. The JS API uses different projections depending on the browser, so they're not going to line up.

Comment: Damn, I thought as much, but felt I'd put the question out there. As that is the right answer, if you put it as an answer, I'll mark it right. Doesn't look like I've got any bites anyway.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The two different APIs use different projection systems. The JS API uses different projections depending on the browser, so they're not going to line up